# How to print the elapsed time in python mpi4py script?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi4py, elapsedtime

Firstly, I know that how to record the elapsed time in the serial Python script.

```
import time

time_start = time.time()
...
time_end = time.time()
print("The elapsed time is", time_end-time_start, "seconds")
```

However, I have no clue about how to print the elapsed time if I enable multi-process by mpi4py.
Could you give me examples or clarifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little late, but I've figured out how to print the elapsed time without a messy output. E.g

```
import time
time_start = time.time()
time.sleep(3)
time_end = time.time()
elapsedTime = time_end - time_start
print(f'The elapsed time is {elapsedTime} seconds')
The elapsed time is 3.000737428665161 seconds
```

To avoid that sloppy output, you can do this:

```
import time
time_start = time.time()
time_end = time.time()
elapsedTime = int(time_end - time_start)
print(f'The elapsed time is {elapsedTime} seconds')
The elapsed time is 3 seconds
```

I hope this helps !